# Comparing Dictionaries with Objects Value of Array in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary

I am having N number of Dictionaries & having array that contains objects.
I need to iterate and check whether value for key EmployeeID of dictionary exists at Object. say obj.empId or not in array.

Dictionary looks like below

```
{
"Message":[
{
        "EmpID": 3749,
        "Dept": 10,
        "EmployeeName": "John",
},
{
},
{
}]
}  //so many dictionaries..not one
```

Example: I already have an array with 10 records say obj.empID holds from 1-10. From service I am getting 10 records say 10 dictionaries. In that key EmpID holds values 5-15.

So, How can I iterate the loop so that to identify that new records are retrieved with different EmpID's then existing Records.

Here is the Code I have done so far..

```
NSArray *responseArray=responseDict[@"Message"];

for (NSDictionary *dict in responseDict[@"Message"]) {
    for (id key in responseDict) {
         if ([key isEqualToString:@"EmpID"]) {
              for (Employees *empObj in emparray)
                  {
                     BOOL isExists=YES;;

                    if (![empObj.empid isEqualToString:[responseDict objectForKey:key]]) {
                       isExists=NO;
                       break;

                       //here I need to do the logic..
                    }
                  }
             }
       }
 }
```

But it will not get accurate results or logic is nor correct..

Please suggest any better solutions for above task or where I am going wrong..

Any Ideas or suggestions are appreciated..

Thanks..,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using so many loops, you may follow below code to check record is exist ot not.

```
 NSArray *responseArray=responseDict[@"Message"];
 for (Employees *empObj in emparray)
 {
       BOOL isExists=NO;           
       if ([[responseArray valueForKey:@"EmpID"]containsObject:empObj.empid]) {
             isExists=YES;
             NSLog(@"%@ EmpID Exist",empObj.empid);
                    //here I need to do the logic..
       }else{
             NSLog(@"%@ EmpID Not Exist",empObj.empid);
       }
}
```

Comment: responseArray have n number of dictionaries... not one. Your logic is meant if response array contains 1 dictionary only..Thanks for answering.

Comment: containsObject is use for Array only. If you log [responseArray valueForKey:@"EmpID"] then you will get array of EmpID.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use iterations, Code smartly, Use following code...

```
NSArray *responseArray=responseDict[@"Message"];
NSArray * empIdResponseArray = [responseArray valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.EmpID"];
NSArray * empIdLocalArray = [emparray valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.empid"];

NSMutableSet *empIdResponseSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray: empIdResponseArray];
NSSet *empIdLocalSet = [NSSet setWithArray: empIdLocalArray];
[empIdResponseSet intersectSet: empIdLocalSet];
NSArray *commonElementArray = [empIdResponseSet allObjects];

NSMutableArray *newElementArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:empIdResponseArray];
[newElementArray removeObjectsInArray:commonElementArray];

for (int index = 0; index < newElementArray.count; index++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary * dictEmp = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[newElementArray objectAtIndex:index]];
    NSLog(@"EMPLOYEE = %@",dictEmp);
    // Add your Logic for new records only....
    // Enjoy :)
}
```